# Pygame displays blank boxes instead of correct character

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, special-characters, hindi

I'm using PyGame to draw some Hindi and other languages used in India or Malayalam (etc. `ថ្ងៃ`). I checked websites like Twitter which supports multiple languages, uses the `Leelawadee UI` font to display text, so I added it to the script but got blank space like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E1ZM.png).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
pygame.init()
font_size = 1024
font = pygame.font.SysFont('LeelawUI', font_size)
text = font.render(text, True, (27, 149, 224), background)
pygame.image.save(text, output_path)
```

I've tried another font and got a different space box like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkPls.jpg)

Also, ts there a library that can handle the mis-marked stress or vowels in this language? When I type-in word like [`കേരളബ്ലാസ്റ്റേഴ്സ്`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2gpt.png), it seems the program doesn't understand correctly that this is a word and not a discrete letter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The font size is far to large try 64 instead of 1024. If that doesn't work, then try a different font: `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, font_size)`

Comment: Be sure the font you're using supports the characters you want to use. The pygame default font will not support Hindi characters.

Comment: I was found that websites like Twitter are using the system font `Leelawadee UI` to display the word `ថ្ងៃ`, But it still doesn't work after I specify the supported font in the script. @Starbuck5

Comment: @jerrylin07 Pygame has trouble supporting it: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/464

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Unifont](https://unifoundry.com/unifont/) as font. I tested it, the `.ttf` file should work. You just need to install it on your system, and it's done.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Unifont renders the characters.]